# How to stop a function from running with another function through class Objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I just started learning about Object Oriented Javascript and i need some help figuring out how to cancel/stop a function from executing through another function.
I'm building (not really building just practicing) a `class Music` with a constructor holding a few parameters and basically i want to play and pause the music when i want.

I thought of making it bit interesting if i could count the seconds the moment i play the song and if i reach the amount of the seconds the song lasts to stop/pause the counter and continue playing it later on at the time i stopped.

The issue i'm having is I want to pause the counter but it seems that the counter continues to execute.

I have two functions within my class object. a `play()` and `pause()` functions.
At first i execute the `play()` function and before the "music" ends i execute the `pause()` which is suppose to stop the counter.

I tried adding to the constructor a patameter: `this.isPlaying = false` and when `play()` runs `this.isPlaying` becomes `true` and if i run `pause()` `this.isPlaying` becomes `false` again, stops the counter and gives me the amount of seconds it counted.

I do get the seconds back when i run `pause()` but the `play()` function is still running regardless.

```
class Music {
  constructor(title, uploader, seconds, isPlaying, startTime) {
    this.title = title;
    this.uploader = uploader;
    this.seconds = seconds;
    this.isPlaying = false;
    this.startTime = 0;
  }

  play() {
    if (!this.isPlaying && this.startTime == 0) {
      this.isPlaying = true;
      console.log('The song: ' + this.title + ' Started');
      var startSong = setInterval(() => {
        this.startTime++;
        if (this.startTime == this.seconds) {
          this.isPlaying = false;
          clearInterval(startSong);
          console.log("song ended");
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      console.log(this.startTime);
      return;
    }
  }

  pause() {
    // console.log(this.isPlaying);
    console.log("executed pause");
    this.isPlaying = false;
  }
}

var fstSong = new Music('Stairways to Heaven', 'Pablo Fransisco', 15);
fstSong.play();
```

I'm looking for the `pause()` to stop the counter and set the `fstSong.startTime` to the second that it stopped to.

Comment: You're not clearing your interval on `pause()`

Comment: You have to make the interval id a property of the class too. I would suggest putting the interval code in its own method for easier readability

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the interval declaring a global variable which you are using for setting up the interval and clearing the interval calling the pause function

```
class Music {
  constructor(title, uploader, seconds, isPlaying, startTime) {
    this.title = title;
    this.uploader = uploader;
    this.seconds = seconds;
    this.isPlaying = false;
    this.startTime = 0;
  }

  play() {
    if (!this.isPlaying && this.startTime == 0) {
      this.isPlaying = true;
      console.log('The song: ' + this.title + ' Started');
      //setting a global variable 
      window.startSong = setInterval(() => {
        this.startTime++;
        if (this.startTime == this.seconds) {
          this.isPlaying = false;
          clearInterval(window.startSong);
          console.log("song ended");
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      console.log(this.startTime);
      return;
    }
  }

  pause() {
    // console.log(this.isPlaying);
    console.log("executed pause");
    this.isPlaying = false;
    clearInterval(window.startSong);// clearing the interval on click function
  }
} 


var fstSong = new Music("song title","song uploader", 15);
fstSong.play();

//Calling pause function on click.
fstSong.pause();
```